# Dynamic load of fat jar's

Tags: java, scala, jar, classloader, uberjar

Using something like one-jar or sbt-assembly, what is the correct way to dynamically load a class from a fat jar?  Single jar example:

```
val loader = new  URLClassLoader(Array(new File(jarName).toURI.toURL), this.getClass().getClassLoader())
var classToLoad = Class.forName (pluginName, true, loader)
var method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod (methodName)
var instance = classToLoad.newInstance ()
var result = method.invoke (instance)
Console.println("Result: " + result)
```

This works fine for my package made jar, but if I create it via one-jar or assembly, it gets a  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.  Do I need a custom class loader (and if so, where is it?) Or is there a special syntax needed on the class or package name?

Thanks!

-Greg

(Example in Scala, but more than happy with a Java example!)

Comment: Have you verified that the class you wish to load is indeed included in the jar?

Comment: Sure - in the one-jar, the jar for all the deps + my project is there. If I extract the jars, my class is here.  For assembly, it's also there.

.... and that might be the answer?  When I want to use it, extract the content of the fat jar and then load from those extracted files.  Seems like having a fat jar-aware class loader would make more sense, and I could also go do that (but am trying to figure out the correct way, not just get it working)

Comment: Then the most likely explanation is that you have a mistake with the jar path. If you want to load class `foo.bar.Clazz`, you should be able to find file `foo/bar/Clazz.class` in the fat jar file. I can use your approach above to load any class from a fat jar created with sbt-assembly without problem. So your path must be wrong. Perhaps it is relative to the wrong base? Try using the absolute file path. Verify that `new File(jarName).isFile` returns `true`.

Comment: Well THANKS! For Assembly, that was it - I had a space at the end of the path!  Any ideas on jars made by https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar?  I did verify the path is correct on that one (but getting a ClassNotFound).  As everything in that fat jar is a jar, I'm assuming I need a special class loader?

Comment: I have never used sbt-onejar, but `URLClassLoader` won't handle nested jars, so if that is the case, you will need indeed a custom class loader.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help in pointing out the "problem" with assembly.  If anyone knows a class loader for sbt-onejar, that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a mistake with the jar path. If you want to load class `foo.bar.Clazz`, you should be able to find file `foo/bar/Clazz.class` in the fat jar file.

I can use your approach above to load any class from a fat jar created with sbt-assembly without problem.

Try using the absolute file path. Verify that `new File(jarName).isFile` returns `true`.

The `URLClassLoader` requires that the classes are directly accessible inside the jar. Nested jars are not supported.